# Python: Create text file, write to it, replace string

Tags: python, string, text, replace, io

I am creating a file, writing to it, then I want to replace a string. I have everything working, except the replace. I have tried re.sub, str.replace, etc. I can't figure it out.

```
target_string = 'foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar'
file = open(source_file, "w+")
file.write(target_string)
target_string = re.sub('4', '55', target_string)

Desired Output: foo55bar5555foobar555555foobar, foo55bar
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official terminology for what you have got wrong is the *`sequencing`* of your `code`.

You write the `target_string` to your file before doing the `re.sub` on it! You need to switch these operations around so you `write` the modified `string` to the `file`:

```
target_string = 'foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar'
file = open(source_file, "w+")
target_string = re.sub('4', '55', target_string)
file.write(target_string)
```

---

Also, when you are working with `files`, you should ideally use a `with` statement as if the program throws an `error` before you call `file.close()` (which I assume you are doing later), you will lead into problems.

So, your final `code` should look something like:

```
target_string = 'foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar'
with open(source_file, "w+") as f:
    target_string = re.sub('4', '55', target_string) #could be moved out of with
    file.write(target_string)
```

Comment: ha my understanding was backwards.. i thought i had to place the string before editing it.. thank you.. that makes a lot of sense

Comment: @chrissmit.yam90 Don't worry about it, its an easy mistake to make. Please `accept` to show this solved your problem... (grey tick next to my answer --> green)

Comment: i will in 5 minutes.. it gave me a prompt to wait

Answer (score 2):

Try this, before writing the target string do the replacement and close the file:

```
target_string = 'foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar'
file = open(source_file,"w")
target_string= re.sub('4', '55', target_string)
file.write(target_string)
file.close()

OR

target_string = 'foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar'
with open(source_file,"w") as f:
  target_string = re.sub('4', '55', target_string)
  f.write(target_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the string before you write to file.

Switch your last two lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
target_string = 'foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar' 
final_string = ''
seen_val = False 
for i in target_string:
   if i.isdigit():
      if seen_val:
         final_string += str(int(i)+1)*2
      else:
          final_string += str(int(i)+1)*2
          seen_val = True
   else:
       final_string += i
       seen_val = False
```

Output:

```
'foo55bar5555foobar555555foobar, foo55bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

here  (does also a bonus backup of the text file) :P

```
import fileinput

# CREATE / WRITE
f = open("test.txt","w+")
f.write("foo4bar44foobar444foobar, foo4bar")
f.close()

# REPLACE
with fileinput.FileInput("test.txt", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace("4", "55"), end='')
```

if you don't need the backup file to compare just remove  `backup='.bak'` form the arguments passed inside `fileinput.FileInput`

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to the file before editing the text.

You should open, edit, then write.